# Trabajar sobre un menu con items dentro de un NavigationView en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, menú, android-drawerlayout

Buena tardes,

Me gustaría plantear un problema al que no encuentro solución en la programación Android.

Resulta que tengo un menú deslizante implementado bajo dos estructuras, un header y un listMenu a mi modo de ver. Accedo al header perfectamente bajo la siguiente linea de código:

```
navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View navHeader = navView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView usuario_header = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.username);
TextView correo_header = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.emailNavegador);
```

Haciendo esto, consigo una referencia al header y puedo modificar dos TextView que en este caso es el nombre del usuario y el correo asociado.

Mi problema está a la hora de trabajar con el menú, ya que no se controlar cuando se está pulsando un item u otro y tras la pulsación, cargar un layout asociado a el.

Pongo el código que implementa mi menú deslizante y una imagen que ilustra dicho código.

Layout del activity_principal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".PrincipalActivity">
<!-- Contenido Principal -->
<include layout="@layout/main_content" />
<!-- Menú Deslizante -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" /></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Layout de main_content

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:text="Holis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/textMain" />
</RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Layout de nav_header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
android:background="@drawable/material_background3"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/header_left_padding"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:id="@+id/header">
<!-- Imagen de perfil -->
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle_image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/perfil_image_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/perfil_image_size"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/pacoalba"
    app:border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:border_width="1dp" />
<!-- Nombre de Usuario -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<!-- Correo de la cuenta -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailNavegador"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" /></LinearLayout>
```

Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_noticias"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_libro"
        android:title="@string/noticias_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_sesion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sesion"
        android:title="@string/sesion_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_mapa"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mapa"
        android:title="@string/mapa_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rutas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rutas"
        android:title="@string/rutas_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_eventos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_eventos"
        android:title="@string/eventos_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_alertas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_alertas"
        android:title="@string/alertas_item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_multimedia"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_multimedia"
        android:title="@string/multimedia_item" />
    <!-- Sección de configuración -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/configuration_section"
        android:title="@string/configuracion_item">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
                android:title="@string/log_out_item" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Aqui adjunto la imagen.[image: Imagen de la aplicación y su menu.]

Muchísimas gracias por todo.

Comment: No entendí muy bien la pregunta,  deseas detectar al dar click  en un elemento del menú y realizar una acción?

Comment: Exactamente Elena, deseo dar click en Noticias y que aparezca un layout asociado a Noticias. Dar click en Sesion y que aparezca su layout. 

En concepto, es fácil, pero en código no sabría que hacer ni donde colocarlo.

Gracias por su interés.

Answer (score 1):

según lo que entiendo, es que necesitas implementar el listener del *NavigationView*, para esto debes sobreescribir el método:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch(id){
            case R.id.nav_noticias:
            //TODO Mostrar Activity de noticias
            return true;
            case R.id.nav_sesion:
            //TODO Mostrar Activity de sesion
            return true;
            }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
```

espero que esto sea lo que nececitas, y si no, por favor especifica más a profundidad el problema.

Salu2

Comment: La idea es que, al yo hacer click en Noticias, me cargue un layout diferente que si hago click en Series. Digamos, un layout por cada menu. Lo que no se, debido a la estructura compleja que he realizado y mis pocos conocimientos de Android, cómo debería programar dicha acción.

Comment: Por otro lado, me está dando error esa funcion en el Android estudio a la hora de hacer @Override, como si no existiese esa función, tuviese mal los parámetros o estuviese mal escrita (mayusculas, minusculas...)

En la API de Android aparece dicha función pero los parámetros son diferentes. No recibe un MenuItem, recibe un integer y un long.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnNavigationListener.html#onNavigationItemSelected(int,%20long)